# Trying to connect to shared folder in Java

Tags: java, android, jcifs

I'm trying to connect to a local shared folder via local network on my smartphone but each time I'm getting the same error that `Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/192.168.1.149`

I tried different jcifs vers(1.3.19,1.3.14-kohsuke-1,1.2.9)

```
            try {

                String path = "smb://192.168.1.149/Printscreen/";
                NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("","","");
                SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);

                String[] files = smbFile.list();

                for (String fileName : files) {
                    Log.e("Log", "File: " + fileName);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("", "", e);
            }
```

Full error message

```
E/: jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/192.168.1.149
    jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:215)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
        at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.readn(Transport.java:29)
        at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.peekKey(SmbTransport.java:388)
        at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:288)
        at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.doConnect(SmbTransport.java:319)
        at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:241)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

        at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:258)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

        at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.connect(SmbTransport.java:309)
        at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:156)
        at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:911)
        at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:957)
        at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
        at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getType(SmbFile.java:1285)
        at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doEnum(SmbFile.java:1736)
        at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.list(SmbFile.java:1712)
        at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.list(SmbFile.java:1609)
        at com.example.abc_dsi1.storagehelper.DataChecker$AsyncTaskRunner.onPostExecute(DataChecker.java:150)
        at com.example.abc_dsi1.storagehelper.DataChecker$AsyncTaskRunner.onPostExecute(DataChecker.java:48)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```